# canvas.clipPath() show clipped view but not clickable behind view in android

Tags: android, canvas, view

[image: i want to create this type of view]
I have Main Activity and one DrawViewEdit canvas class
so for that i have added view1 and view2 in main activity and on view1 and view2 i have performed canvas.clipPath()
I want to perform click operation outside view1 area but in result i got view1 how can i get View2 click?
[image: This is my issue]

Here is my canvas class

```
public class DrawViewEdit extends FrameLayout {

    Context context;
    Path path;
    JSONObject layersJsonObject;

    int displayWidth, displayHeight;
    int left, top,index;

    private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public DrawViewEdit(Context context, JSONObject layersJsonObject, int displayHeight, int displayWidth,
                        int left, int top) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.layersJsonObject = layersJsonObject;
        this.displayHeight = displayHeight;
        this.displayWidth = displayWidth;
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;

        try {
            path = new Path();

            double w = (Float.parseFloat("" + displayWidth) / 720.0) * 2.0;
            double h = (Float.parseFloat("" + displayHeight) / 1080.0) * 2.0;

            path.rMoveTo(Float.valueOf("" + ((Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x1")) * w) + left)),
                    Float.valueOf("" + ((Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y1")) * h) + top)));
            path.lineTo(Float.valueOf("" + ((Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x2")) * w) + left)),
                    Float.valueOf("" + ((Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y2")) * h) + top)));
            path.lineTo(Float.valueOf("" + ((Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x3")) * w) + left)),
                    Float.valueOf("" + ((Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y3")) * h) + top)));
            path.lineTo(Float.valueOf("" + ((Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x4")) * w) + left)),
                    Float.valueOf("" + ((Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y4")) * h) + top)));
            path.lineTo(Float.valueOf("" + ((Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x1")) * w) + left)),
                    Float.valueOf("" + ((Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y1")) * h) + top)));
            path.close();

                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        init();

    }

    public DrawViewEdit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DrawViewEdit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(displayWidth, displayHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Here is my Activity class function in which i performed on click

```
private void setViews() {
    try {
        JSONArray layersJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("layers");

        for (int i = 0; i < layersJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject layerJsonObject = layersJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            drawView = new DrawViewEdit(EditActivity.this, layerJsonObject, displayHeight, displayWidth, left, top);
            drawView.setTag(i);

drawView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, "" + view.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});        
}    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add only 1 view and then you can detect the area where the user clicked.

Comment: @NigamPatro i'm adding this view programatically in loop and its not fix 2 its vary according to data so i need to add multiple views.

Comment: Yah got that. But, what clipPath does is clipping the canvas only not the view.

Comment: @NigamPatro Ya that's the issue. Do you know the other way of this?

Comment: I have not much idea, but can you try this sample

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ClippingBasic